# RSA alternative for 40bit data

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm searching for a **Public-key cryptography** algorithm to encrypt a 40bit data.

I don't want the output to be longer than 64 bit (it's better to be 40bits)

The algorithm must work with a public and private key.

is there any secure algorithm ?

Comment: *is there any secure algorithm*. Not that I'm aware of. You can achieve an *amortized* length of only slightly more than 64-bits by only occasionally sending a new, say, blowfish (a 64-bit block cipher), key every n messages and using ECDH for key exchange. This gives an average bit length of 256/n + 64 bits. By making n large you can get very close to 64-bits. This uses long-term ECDH keys is thus is far from ideal

Comment: Why do you have such a limit in this modern world?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about cryptography and not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

Seems unlikely to exist. The problem you have to overcome with encrypting to 40 bits is that, given the small message size, it's easy to encrypt all possible plaintexts and compare them to the ciphertext. I don't think an additional 24 bits will help much, but I'm not a professional cryptographer.